# Why does the program crash at the line that moves the address of a string to BX?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox, rpn

I have this RPN calculator program in TASM that calculates an expression in the string data_stack:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    data_stack db '3 4 +', 0
    top equ 0
    result db 0

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov bx, offset data_stack
    mov cl, 1
read_argument:
    mov dx, [bx]
    cmp dx, 0
    je calculate_result
    push dx
    inc cl
    inc bx
    jmp read_argument
calculate_result:
    jmp calculate_expression
calculate_expression:
    pop bx
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, '+'
    je add_operands
    cmp al, '-'
    je subtract_operands
add_operands:
    pop bx
    add al, [bx]
    jmp calculate_expression
subtract_operands:
    pop bx
    sub al, [bx]
    jmp calculate_expression
print_result:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, al
    int 21h
exit_program:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
end start
```

But it crashes in debugging mode at line:

```
mov bx, offset data_stack
```

I work in DOSBox and I don't know the reason, so should I use another register or what?

Comment: What debugger are you using? What commands do you use to assemble, link, and run the program?

Comment: As to your question, something else must be going on because a `mov bx, imm16` instruction cannot possibly fault.

Comment: @ecm I'm using TASM in dosbox. First tasm rpn.asm, then tlink rpn.obj and finally td rpn (debugger) and i press F8 to go step by step, at line mov bx, offset data_stack it crashes (freezes)

Comment: `data_stack` in memory looks like `33 20 34 20 2b 00`, after that is `result` which is `00`. In `read_argument` loop `dx` in each iteration contains `20 33`, `34 20`,`20 34`,`2b 20`,`00 2b` and last `00` is combined with `result=00` so `cmp dx,0` works and code jumps to `calculate_result`. Values pushed to stack from `dx` now are popped to `bx` and these are adresses which points to wrong memory places. An after that I think program is in infinite loop because values in `al` are diffrent from `+` and `-`.

Comment: @Nassau and how to solve or fix the program please ?

Answer (score 2):

I tested few rpn strings and debugger shows good results.
It works with digits `1 - 9` and result should be in range `-128,255`.
Each character in string is separated by space (20h).
I also added `flag` in cl register just to make sure that stack contains 2 values.

https://www-stone.ch.cam.ac.uk/documentation/rrf/rpn.html

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    data_stack db '9 9 + 9 9 * - 8 8 * - 1 -',0 
    ; strings tested
    ; 3 + 4
    ; '3 4 + ', 0
    
    ; 5 * 3 + 9/3 + 9
    ; '5 3 * 9 3 / + 9 + ',0
    
    ; 9 * 2 * 5 + 7 + 8 * 5
    ; '9 2 * 5 * 7 + 8 5 * +',0
    
    ; 9 - 5 * 3 + 7 * 7 + 3 - 8 * 9
    ; '9 5 3 * - 7 7 * + 3 + 8 9 * -',0         
    
    ; 9 + 9 - 9 * 9 - 8 * 8 - 1
    ; '9 9 + 9 9 * - 8 8 * - 1 -',0     
    add_zero db 0
    save_bx dw ?
    result db 0

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov bx, offset data_stack       
    sub bx,2

    mov cl, 0           ; flag, if digits are on the stack
                        ; 0 = no values available, no operation
                        ; 1 = 1 value is on the stack, no operation
                        ; 2+ = more than 2 values are on the stack, operation allowed
    
    xor dx,dx
    
read_argument:  
    add bx,2
    
    mov dl, [bx]        ; ASCII code for '1' - '9' = 31h - 39h
                        ; '*' = 2ah 
                        ; '/' = 2fh
                        ; '+' = 2bh
                        ; '-' = 2dh
    
    cmp dl,0            ; end of string
    jz print_result
    
    check_sign:
        cmp dl, 2fh     
        ja check_1
        
    check_values_on_stack:
        cmp cl, 2       ; 2 values are on the stack, so we can do arithmetic operation
        jae arithmetic_operation
        jmp no_operation
        
    check_1:
        cmp dx, 31h     ; ok if >= 1 
        jb check_next_value     
    
    check_9:
        cmp dx, 39h     ; ok if <= 9 
        ja check_next_value
    
        inc cl
        
    value_ok:       
        sub dl,30h      ; we want digits 1 - 9 not ASCII values of '1' - '9'
        push dx         ; save digit on stack

        jmp check_next_value

    no_operation:
        xor cl,cl       ; reset flag

    check_next_value:       
        jmp read_argument

    arithmetic_operation:
        mov [save_bx], bx   ; save address of element in string
    
        pop bx              ; pop digits
        pop ax          
        
        cmp dl,2ah          ; mul
        jz mul_op
        cmp dl,2fh          ; div
        jz div_op
        cmp dl,2bh          ; add
        jz add_op
        cmp dl,2dh          ; sub
        jz sub_op       
        
        mul_op:
            mul bl
            jmp common
            
        div_op:
            div bl
            jmp common  
            
        add_op:
            add al,bl
            jmp common  
            
        sub_op:
            sub al,bl
            
        common:
            push ax
            dec cl      ; after operation one value is on the stack
            mov bx, [save_bx]   ; save address of element in string
            mov [result],al
            jmp check_next_value
            

print_result:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, [result]            ; show ASCII char equal to result
    int 21h
    
exit_program:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
end start
```

Comment: And what I want integer numbers ?

Comment: You mean greater than 9?

Comment: Yes, so -128 - 128

Comment: You want input string to have both positive and negative values? Like -13 4 + 2 -4 - +

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: You have to add code which detects all possible entries. If `-` is arithmetic operation or negative value.

Comment: OK thanks, and what if only natural numbers, so for example 1 - 128?

Comment: Well, this won't work in my code because operations are on single digits. Add some code which detects this also if value is greater than 9. After each character there is space char so if You want bigger values just check if after each digit is space or another digit.

Comment: You could tighten the code a bit (shaving off 9 bytes). It suffers from repeating itself. You wrote `push ax` `dec cl` 3x too many! I suggest: ... `add_op` `add al, bl` `jmp common` `sub_op:` `sub al,bl` `common:` `push ax` `dec cl` `mov bx,[save_bx]` ...

Comment: @SepRoland Yes, thank You for correcting my mistakes. Now the code looks better. :)